# Saving WiFi credentials to EEPROM on ESP8266

Tags: arduino, arduino-esp8266, eeprom

I am using the following code to save and load credentials to and from EEPROM:

```
void loadCredentials() {
  EEPROM.begin(512);
  EEPROM.get(0, ssid);
  EEPROM.get(0+sizeof(ssid), password);
  char ok[2+1];
  EEPROM.get(0+sizeof(ssid)+sizeof(password), ok);
  EEPROM.end();
  if (String(ok) != String("OK")) {
    ssid[0] = 0;
    password[0] = 0;
  }
  Serial.println("Recovered credentials:");
  Serial.println(ssid);
  Serial.println(strlen(password)>0?"********":"<no password>");
}

/** Store WLAN credentials to EEPROM */
void saveCredentials() {
  EEPROM.begin(512);
  EEPROM.put(0, ssid);
  EEPROM.put(0+sizeof(ssid), password);
  char ok[2+1] = "OK";
  EEPROM.put(0+sizeof(ssid)+sizeof(password), ok);
  EEPROM.commit();
  EEPROM.end();
  Serial.print("Saving SSID: ");
  Serial.println(ssid);
  Serial.print("Password: ");
  Serial.println(password); 
  Serial.println("Done");
}
```

However, `loadCredentials()` always returns empty or invalid credentials. I cannot quite understand why though as `saveCredentials()` appears to run correctly, and `WiFi.begin(ssid, passaord)` works without any issues (until you reset)

here is the code used to set the credentials into the variables:

```
    if(ssidchange){
      a = String(a);
      a.toCharArray(tempssid, 50);
      ssid = tempssid;
      Serial.print("Done, SSID changed to ");
      Serial.println(ssid);
      ssidchange = false;
    }
    else if(passchange){
      char temppass[50];
      String a2 = String(a);
      a2.toCharArray(temppass, 50);
      ssid = tempssid;
      password = temppass;
      Serial.print("SSID changed to ");
      Serial.println(tempssid);
      Serial.print("and pass changed to ");
      Serial.println(password);
      saveCredentials();
      delay(3000);
      ESP.restart();
    }
```

Tank you very much in advance!

Answer (score 0):

Better way to make a structure which has member like ssid, password etc.
e.g.

```
struct wificredential{
  char ssid[30];
  char pass[30];
}
```

and then storing that whole structure in eeprom at specific address. and later fetch it from same address whenever we want

I have done that to build database for framework [here](https://github.com/Suraj151/esp8266-framework/tree/master/src/database)